# Change permission for a file created by other user in the same group

Tags: centos, permissions, file-server

I have a centos 7 file server and user that can work on shared directory are in group users. With default umask a user is able to create file with the following permissions:

[luca@myserver mydirectory]$ ls -l testfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 luca     users       0 18 giu 13.03 testfile.txt

but when an other user, part of the same group users, try to change permissions on the same file I have

[nick@myserver mydirectory]$ chmod a+x testfile.txt
chmod: cambio dei permessi di "testfile.txt": Operazione non permessa
(change permissions: operation not permitted, sorry for italian)

Why an other user in the same group cannot change file permission for a file that have write permission for user in the same group?

Answer (score 3):

The common rwx permissions only applies to file content. File attributes, like ownership and permissions can only be changed by the **file owner** or **root**.

So if testfile.txt belongs to luca, whatever are the permissions of nick regarding this file, he will be not able to change its permissions.